# What is the scientific term for an analysis or comparison of percentage of two commodities?

Tags: analysis, terminology

My analysis has resulted in a graph where the x-axis is a percentage of one commodity and y-axis is the percentage of another commodity. Is there any concise name or terminology for this kind of analysis? This is my graph:

[image]

Comment: Some additional context is needed to make sense of this graph.  Two curves are plotted, one labeled commodity A and one labeled commodity B, but no common case occurs to me to indicate how these denote variant ways that a "percentage" of one commodity depends or functionally relates to the other.

Comment: Say, commodity A is 'amount of work done' and commodity B is 'number of workers'. I am just looking for a general term, if any, for these kinds of analysis where you compare 2 percentages. I'm not looking for something specific to one particular situation.

Comment: My complaint is that you seem to use "commodity A" and "commodity B" inconsistently, and then ask your Readers to give "a general term" for the graphs.  The numeric percentage of A and B on both monotone curves are zero at a common endpoint and are one ($100\%$) at the other endpoint.  Surely you know why this is a feature of the models being displayed, and surely such a critical feature ought to be reflected in the choice of terminology.  A related notion is a cumulative distribution function.

Comment: But why is that a special property if both the percentages start at 0 and go up to 100? In my example, for instance, you can imagine 1% of workers doing 0.2% of work, 5% of workers doing 3% of work, and so on and so forth until, 90% of workers do 99% of the work, and 100% of workers do 100% of work. This is nothing unusual in my opinion, and in fact fairly common.

Comment: By labeling the $x$-axis `Percentage of B` and the $y$-axis `Percentage of A` you convey to me that each curve expresses a functional relationship between % of B and % of A.  Perhaps you do not intend to convey such relationships, in which case I would suggest separately graphing these curves.  As separate curves they might well be called [cumulative distribution functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).